# Try to use += on string to stack char(s) in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, cs50

I know it sounds real stupid, but It is cuz I just lightly learned Java and Python last year...

now I am try to do C properly with CS50.

on week 2, there is Caesar encipher text program task.

I tried to use += on string to stack char(s) one by one.

And of course it didn't work.

***but is there any other way to do it similarly?***

here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


string encipher(string x, int y);


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string key = argv[1];
    bool num_flag = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++)
    {
        int k = isdigit(key[i]);
        if (k == 0)
        {
            num_flag = true;
        }

    }

    if (num_flag == true)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    }
    else
    {
    int keys = atoi(argv[1]);

    string c = get_string("plaintext: ");
    string ciphertext = encipher(c, keys);
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);
    }
}


string encipher(string x, int y)
{
    string cip = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(x); i++)
    {
        int low = islower(x[i]);
        int upper = isupper(x[i]);

        if (low != 0)
        {
            char lo = x[i] - 97;
            char c = (lo + y) % 26;
            char l = c + 97;
            cip += l;
        }
        else if (upper != 0)
        {
            char up = x[i] - 65;
            char c = (up + y) % 26;
            char u = c + 65;
            cip += u;
        }
        else
        {
            cip += x[i];
        }
    }
    return cip;
}
```

.

I changed code to pass the test, but not perfect either...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


string encipher(string x, int y);


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{



    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    }
    else
    {
        string key = argv[1];
        bool num_flag = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++)
        {
            int k = isdigit(key[i]);
            if (k == 0)
            {
                num_flag = true;
            }
        }

        if (num_flag == true)
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        }
        else
        {
            int keys = atoi(argv[1]);

            string c = get_string("plaintext: ");
            string cipher = encipher(c, keys);
            printf("ciphertext: %s\n", cipher);
        }
    }
}


string encipher(string x, int y)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(x); i++)
    {
        int low = islower(x[i]);
        int upper = isupper(x[i]);

        if (low != 0)
        {
            char lo = x[i] - 97;
            char c = (lo + y) % 26;
            char l = c + 97;
            x[i] = l;
        }
        else if (upper != 0)
        {
            char up = x[i] - 65;
            char c = (up + y) % 26;
            char u = c + 65;
            x[i] = u;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Thanks for helping newbie!

Comment: I don't know cs50.h - does it define the `string` type? As a char*? What you've got might work with C++ strings; with C you'll have to allocate a buffer and track the next index in the buffer, then zero-terminate at the end. Or just copy and modify the input string in-place.

Comment: In my not very humble opinion, CS50 is a bad teaching resource, as it hides some very important things for beginners. Like that `string` is really a type-alias for `char *`. So when you have `string cip;` it really means `char *cip;`. And when you do `cip += x[i]` you don't append to a string, but you add to the *pointer*, making it point somewhere else.

Comment: "but not perfect either..." --> What was the input, output seen and output expected?  What data did you use that was not perfect in testing your code?

Comment: thanks guys! 1 - yes they give us the string data type. 2- I think they just tried to make it easier for beginners to understand 3 - oh program works fine, when they scored me, there was some points said
:( handles lack of key
    expected exit code 1, not 0
:( handles non-numeric key
    expected exit code 1, not 0
:( handles too many arguments
    expected exit code 1, not 0
I think this was because I didn't use return value on if statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with strncat() you can add chars to an existing string.
( strncat(char DESTINATION STRING, const char SOURCE STRING, AMOUNT OF CHARS YOU WANT TO ADD FROM THE SOURCE)  )

Answer (score 0):

In C you can't add string like other high-level languages. You have to use a special function in string.h. Like strcat(first_string, second_string);

An alternative is: char *strncat(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n) to add the first n characters (you can interprete size_t like int).